# How to force iOS not to halve image sizes on legacy displays?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

In order to be consistent with iOS 7, I want to use 1px thick vertical separators in my app. 
To do that, I have created an asset of 1 px width. 
While applying it to legacy displays, iOS resizes the width to 0.5 px. How can I force iOS to retain the width i.e. 1px even for legacy displays?

Comment: post screen shot to easily understand :)

Answer (score 4):

What you are probably seeing is 1px thick on legacy and 2px thick on retina.

In order to support legacy displays, there must be two copies of each asset. Assuming your image is called `image.png`, the legacy one should be at half-resolution, called `image.png` and the high-resolution one should be called `image@2x.png`.